# Fluid Mechanics - Bubbles

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension, buoyancy

Why do gas bubbles initially stick to the walls of the bottle in carbonated drinks? And what happens when we open the cap? How do they separate from the walls?

Comment: I think at a high pressure they try to escape so move outwards and stick to wall

Comment: Actually the tiny defect sites in the wall are where the bubbles actually form... The surface tension of water prevents it from filling those tiny crevices on the wall surface, as a result of which gas is trapped on those regions... In case you heat the system, the gas trapped within expands and we get to see the bubbles on the wall... Supply more heat and they will detach due to obvious imbalances... I have an idea on what mechanism causes this detachment... https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/570601/266637 Now the actual question is, how the bubbles form in case of cold carbonated drinks?